# How to wait for the result on a Okhttp call to use it on a test?

Tags: android, connection, timeout, ping, okhttp

I've created a method to check if my app is able to connect to my server using OkHttp.

This is my test class:

```
public class NetworkTest {

static boolean resultWeb = false;

public static boolean pingTestWeb() {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://www.google.com")//My server address will go here
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
            resultWeb = false;
            Log.i("Error","Failed to connect: "+e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {

            Log.i("Success","Success: "+response.code());
            if (response.code() == 200) {
                resulWeb = true;
            }
        }
    });

    return resultWeb;
}
```

And here is where I'm making the test on my activity on OnCreate():

```
if (NetworkTest.pingTestWeb()) {

        // Do something if true...

    } else {

        // Do something if false, like showing an AlertDialog...
    }
```

The question is, my pingTestWeb have the default Timeout time of 10000ms, how do I make the activity create the AlertDialog only if the pingTestWeb is false? Because it isn't waiting for the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what may be happening here is you're performing the OkHttp call asynchronously, so you're hitting the return statement before the task is complete. For the sake of the test would it be possible to do the OkHttp call synchronously? You can handle the success/failure case with `response.isSuccessful` seen below.

```
   private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

   public void run() throws Exception {
       Request request = new Request.Builder()
           .url("your_url_here")
           .build();

       Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
       if(response.isSuccessful()){
           return true;             
        }else return false;

    }
```

Comment: Just noticed you're calling this test in onCreate. Probably better to leave it asynchronous. You could place the respective return statements in the onFailure and onResponse methods.

Comment: Ok, I understand, my pingTestWeb is in another class, so if I call it on my activityMain it should wait until it gets the return from the pingTestWeb, to proceed, correct? Or as I'm doing it asynchronous it will move forward instead of wait for the response?

Comment: I believe because it's asynchronous it's moving forward. If you use the synchronous method here instead of the asynchronous(using callbacks) this should work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. Update as soon it's done.

Answer (score 15):

You can also use CountDownLatch, in this way you can put async in your test:

```
public class NetworkTest {

static boolean resultWeb = false;

public static boolean pingTestWeb() {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://www.google.com")//My server address will go here
            .build();

    CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
            resultWeb = false;
            Log.i("Error","Failed to connect: "+e.getMessage());
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {

            Log.i("Success","Success: "+response.code());
            if (response.code() == 200) {
                resulWeb = true;
            }
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        }
    });

    countDownLatch.await();
    return resultWeb;
}
```

Comment: I think this is a better answer, because it doesn't make it necessary to change to code for the sake of the test.